# Dropdown 'ul' 'li' getting last value after append values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem getting last value after append values.

**Example:**

```
alert($('#ulscroller li:last-child').last().val());
$('#ulscroller li:last-child').append('<li value="21">21</li><li value="22">22</li><li value="23">23</li>');
alert($('#ulscroller li').last().val());
$('#ulscroller li:last-child').append('<li value="24">24</li><li value="25">25</li><li value="26">26</li>');
alert($('#ulscroller li').last().val());
```

**Alert result:**

```
20
23
25
```

The problem is in result. Two times 24, 25, 26.

Ckeck this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f5v6R/171/

Anyone have idea how to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It looks like it's functionality as it should

Comment: `append()` means it always append to end of the child elements. try `$('#ulscroller').append('<li value="24">24</li><li value="25">25</li><li value="26">26</li>');`

Comment: try using `.after` instead of `.append` and see if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand on what your problem was:

You are starting out with this:

```
<ul id="ulscroller">
    <li value="1" class="selected">1</li>
    <li value="2">2</li>
    ...
    <li value="19">19</li>
    <li value="20">20</li>
</ul>
```

and you want to add some additional `<li>` elements to get this:

```
<ul id="ulscroller">
    <li value="1" class="selected">1</li>
    <li value="2">2</li>
    ...
    <li value="19">19</li>
    <li value="20">20</li>
    <li value="21">21</li>
    <li value="22">22</li>
    <li value="23">23</li>
    <li value="24">24</li>
    <li value="25">25</li>
    <li value="26">26</li>
</ul>
```

Using `$('#ulscroller li:last-child')` selects the last `<li>` in the list, but using `.append()` then adds those new `<li>` elements *into* the last `<li>`, so, after the first append you end up with

```
<ul id="ulscroller">
    <li value="1" class="selected">1</li>
    <li value="2">2</li>
    ...
    <li value="19">19</li>
    <li value="20">20
        <li value="21">21</li>
        <li value="22">22</li>
        <li value="23">23</li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now using `$('#ulscroller li:last-child')` will end up selecting two different `<li>` elements:

```
<li value="20">20
    <li value="21">21</li>
    <li value="22">22</li>
    <li value="23">23</li>
</li>
```

and

```
<li value="23">23</li>
```

The second `append` will then insert the new `<li>` elements into *both* of those, resulting in the repeated 24 25 26. By using `.after()` instead of `.append()` the new `<li>` are added at the same level as the other `<li>`, so that there is only one list and the `$('#ulscroller li:last-child')` will only return one selected element. The comment from @Tamil Selvan would give the same result in this case since `$('#ulscroller').append` would always add the new elements in at the end of the `<ul>`